# Running Headless Webdriver Tests on Ubuntu LTS using Firefox driver

Tags: python, selenium, ubuntu, firefox

I am running python 2.7.12 with selenium version 2.53.6 and firefox 46.0.1. My goal is to run headless tests on an AWS Ubuntu Server 16.04 LTS. This is how I have set it up.

```
# install anaconda
cd ~
wget https://repo.continuum.io/archive/Anaconda2-4.2.0-Linux-x86_64.sh
bash Anaconda2-4.2.0-Linux-x86_64.sh
rm Anaconda2-4.2.0-Linux-x86_64.sh
echo export 'PATH="/home/ubuntu/anaconda2/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc
source .bashrc
conda update conda

# install firefox version 46.0.1
wget https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/46.0.1/linux-x86_64/en-US/firefox-46.0.1.tar.bz2
tar jxf firefox-46.0.1.tar.bz2
rm firefox-46.0.1.tar.bz2

# install pyvirtualdisplay
sudo apt-get install xvfb xserver-xephyr
pip install pyvirtualdisplay

# install selenium version 2.53.6
pip install selenium==2.53.6
```

When I run this code

```
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
from selenium import webdriver

display = Display(visible=0, size=(1024, 768))
display.start()

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.python.org")

driver.quit()
display.stop()
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 55, in __init__
self.binary = firefox_binary or capabilities.get("binary",  FirefoxBinary())
File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/firefox_binary.py", line 47, in __init__
self._start_cmd = self._get_firefox_start_cmd()
File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/firefox_binary.py", line 163, in _get_firefox_start_cmd
" Please specify the firefox binary location or install firefox")
RuntimeError: Could not find firefox in your system PATH. Please specify the firefox binary location or install firefox
```

I've tried to add a link to firefox in the bash profile by running `echo export 'PATH="$PATH:/home/ubuntu/firefox"' >> ~/.bashrc` but that did not fix the issue.

**UPDATE**

I was able to successfully add the path to my bash profile. I am now getting this error

```
"The browser appears to have exited "
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: The browser    appears to have exited before we could connect. If you specified a log_file in the FirefoxBinary constructor, check it for details.
```

Given that I have am already using pyvirtualdisplay, does anyone know of a solution?

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, Firefox is not build for Headless mechanism [Correct me if I am wrong].
You can use [PhantomJs](http://phantomjs.org/) for better handling.